# Images not showing up when viewing HTML code

Tags: html, django

I have an index page for a django project I am working on but the images I attach to the buttons aren't showing up when I view it.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Support Tools</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        .button {
            float: left;
            margin-left: 30px;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            width: 350px;
            height: 150px;
            background: url('/media/img/blank.png');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            cursor: hand;
        }
        .button img {
            position: relative;
            left: 20px;
            top: 10px;
        }
        .button div {
            font-family: Trebuchet MS, Calibri;
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 22pt;
            text-align: center;
            position: relative;
            top: -100px;
            left: 120px;
            width: 220px;
        }
        .title {
            font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, Arial, Verdana;
            font-size: 18pt;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        a, a:link, a:visited, a:active, a:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        </style>
        <!--[if lte IE 6]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/supersleight-min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body id="b">
        <p class="title">GAI Support Tools</p>
        <a href="/eam/">
            <div class="button">
                <img src="/media/img/tools.png" />
                <div>EAM<br />Support Tool</div>
            </div>
        </a>            
        <a href="/admin/minisar/">
            <div class="button">
                <img src="/media/img/database.png" />
                <div>miniSAR<br />Administration</div>
            </div>
        </a>            
        <a href="/ai_stats/">
            <div class="button">
                <img src="/media/img/chart.png" />
                <div>Web Service<br />Dashboard</div>
            </div>
        </a>            
        <a href="/health/production/">
            <div class="button">
                <img src="/media/img/monitor.png" />
                <div>&nbsp;Web Service<br />Health</div>
            </div>
        </a>            
        <a href="/toys/user/">
            <div class="button">
                <img src="/media/img/users.png" />
                <div>User<br />Search</div>
            </div>
        </a>            
        <a href="/toys/ud_data_extract/">
            <div class="button">
                <img src="/media/img/database.png" />
                <div>UD Data<br />Extract</div>
            </div>
        </a>            
        <a href="/solutions/">
            <div class="button">
                <img src="/media/img/solutions.png" />
                <div>Solution Matrix</div>
            </div>
        </a>            
        <a href="/directentry/">
            <div class="button">
                <img src="/media/img/dice.png" />
                <div style="text-align: left; padding-left: 2.5em;"><u>DI</u>rect<br /><u>C</u>XML<br /><u>E</u>ntry</div>
            </div>
        </a>            
        <script type="text/javascript">
        supersleight.limitTo("b");
        supersleight.init();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Here is what it looks like when I view the page in a browser]
It just shows up as a broken image link, but all of the .png files are in the `/media/img/` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a few steps you need.

1. You will have to insert `{% load static %}` on the top of your template file
2. You will have to create a folder named **static** and **media** on your root of your application
3. On your `project/settings.py` file you need to tell django where to look for your static files
4. in your template you will have to add a static call (see step 4)
5. modify your project urls.py

mytemplate.html ... (step 1) example

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

settings.py (step 3)

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join('staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

step 4

```
<img src="{% static 'media/img/tools.png' %}" alt="image of ..." class="img-responsive img-rounded" > 
or if the image come from a Model object
<img src="{{object.image}}" alt="image of {{object.description}}" class="img-responsive img-rounded" >
```

so in your static folder your will have this structure
**static > media > img > tools.png**

but I suggest you to remove media
**static > img > tools.png**

And if your image comes from a Model object then automatically Django will go look on the folder media

media > tools.png

step 5

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I will give it a shot once I can get the manage.py server running. I'm very certain this will fix the issue. We are moving this app from one server to another and updating some of the python packages in the process, seeing as the ones we weren't using are no longer available. We are having issues with the outdated Django code we were using. Will be a painstaking process.

Answer (score 2):

Not familiar with django or what webserver you're using but occasionally there's extra stuff going on under the covers depending on what you're using to host the files. If you put 127.0.0.1:8000/media/img/monitor.png in your browser does it load your image? I suspect that it isn't serving those images rather than an html issue.

maybe something in one of these guys will help:

- [django not serving static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594145/django-not-serving-static-files)
- [Django runserver not serving static files in development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398600/django-runserver-not-serving-static-files-in-development)

Answer (score 1):

Add below line in urls.py and check once.

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```