# django development server not serving static files

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

Same question as [this 7 year old one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594145/django-not-serving-static-files/29032984) but the solutions don't help plus I'm using django 3 so in my opinion clearly not a duplicate.

I followed exactly the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/) about static files.

settings file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
DEBUG = True
```

Folder Structure:

```
---my_project
------my_project
------app1
------static
---------css
------------mystyle.css
```

Template:

```
  {% load static %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/mystle.css" %}">
```

When browsing to the site I get a 404 Not Found. The link is pointing to the correct directory:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/mystyle.css
```

With further search and looking at the documentation (which in my opinion is unclear) I also found the setting `STATIC_ROOT` and set it accordingly but that did not help either.

```
#BASE_DIR = path to project dir
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you added urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

Comment: see my answer. I just figured it out. In my opinion the documentation is confusing and doesn't show a nice, full example of how the setting should be.

Comment: Funny, the same typo as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60859511/django-doesnt-load-css-file/60861806#60861806

Answer (score 1):

Trying to solve this for hours and then when you hit send on the post you find the solution. For me the django documentation is unclear and confusing hence I'm adding an answer instead of deleting my question.

> Your project will probably also have static assets that aren’t tied to
>   a particular app. In addition to using a static/ directory inside your
>   apps, you **can define a list of directories (STATICFILES_DIRS) in your
>   settings file where Django will also look for static files.**

With emphasis on "can" and "also". This implies this setting isn't needed and STATIC_URL is enough. But it isn't. It's aboslutley required or else you get the 404.

This leads to below settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
DEBUG = True
```

to make it work.

Comment: STATICFILES_DIRS is described correctly in the docs: it is an optional additional list of directories to be searched and collected info STATIC_ROOT. In shown conf you don't have STATIC_ROOT defined which is a mistake. In your case you need STATIC_ROOT only. STATIC_URL is not a folder - it is an root URL under which your files can be queried via web.

Comment: With STATIC_ROOT only it doesn't work. In fact the documentation I linked doesn't mention it for development, only under deployment. The documentation might work for someone familiar with django but since I'm new to django, it's very confusing and there is not example shown with all settings that actually work. If I omit `STATICFILES_DIRS` it simply doesn't work.

Comment: Then you have error somewhere else. STATICFILES_DIRS is absolutely not required for static files to work.

Comment: Thanks. I had the same issue. Only after including "STATICFILES_DIRS" did it work.